# When to check whether GC is needed?

Tags: compiler-construction, garbage-collection

I am writing a compiler for a garbage collected language, and am confused about how I know when I should run the garbage collector.

There are two ways that I can think of:

1. To put a GC check before every heap allocation. Therefore, if any allocation is about to fail, we run the GC.
2. To run the GC check "periodically", and perform a GC sweep once we are "dangerously" low on space.

I am using the second scheme currently, thus I have a GC check at the beginning of every function entry to ensure that the GC check is performed often enough.

Does anyone know where I can find more information on this subject?

Comment: Typically, memory allocation in a GC language is done by simply incrementing a pointer. If the pointer increments past the end of the heap, then it's time to GC. If you want to learn about GC implementations, [Paul Wilson's survey paper](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/94-02-143) is quite good.

Comment: Thank you for that brief and clear answer. The survey paper is very helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

To your question "Does anyone know where I can find more information on this subject" the best reference is  [Paul Wilson's survey paper](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/94-02-143) as pointed by the @ Raymond Chen .

To have overview of existing garbage collector algorithms please check this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf)

Among the two ways you have mentioned (1) and (2) , I feel check has to be made in both ways .

Assuming you have defined your heap with certain constraints .(prime constraints being `size_t maximumSize ,  base , limit ,NoOfBytesAllocated`) . So to that heap structure adding few more fields like `limitForGcInSizeMinor ,limitForGcInSizeMajor  limitForGcInObjects` would tackle GC situation in better way(If your heap structure already has this fields please ignore).

SO whenever allocation >= limitForGcInSizeMinor perform GcMinor(can be stop the world mechanism or can be concurrent)  . if allocation reaches limitForGcInSizeMajor then perform GCMajor(something like stop the world ).
I main reason for dividing GCMinor and GCMajor is to reduce the effect of GC spike (when stop the world mechanism happens) to minimum .

So in all along GC we followed (2) way I mean periodicallyas well as checking it using heap allocation . Al-tough i borrowed it from CMS algorithm .